# How to find out when the QQuickItem-derived class object is initialized?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I've got class that inherits from `QQuickItem` and inside I'm operating on its `width` `height` properties. I'm also exposing my own properties.

```
class MyQQuickItem : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QUrl source MEMBER m_source NOTIFY sourceChanged)

    public:
    explicit MyQQuickItem(QQuickItem *a_parent = Q_NULLPTR);
     ~PDFPage();

    signals:
    void sourceChanged(const QUrl a_source);

    private:
    QUrl m_source;
};
```

In qml:

```
...
MyQQuickItem
{
    width: parent.width / 2
    height: parent.height
    source: "someSource"
    Component.onCompleted
    {
        console.log("component onCompleted");
    }
}
```

When `sourceChanged` is emmited I'm working on `width` `height` properties, but with the first emit they are not initialized yet, and `Component.onCompleted` is called after my NOTIFY signal.

I can check if component is ready before getting `width` and `height` by calling [isComponentComplete](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#isComponentComplete) and execute my code when it is, but I can't find out when it happens and the initial value of `source` is skipped when it is not.

Of course I could create slot `'itemReady'` and call it from `Component.onCompleted`, but I have many QMLs using my class and I will create more in the future, so I don't want to make copy-paste job.

I also do not want to set the source in `Component.onCompleted`.

Connecting to `widthChanged`, and `heightChanged` signals isn't also good idea, because I'm resizing my item very frequently, and I don't want to execute my code then.

Is there any way to get `completed` signal from C++?

**EDIT:**

I did as @Mitch said - overriten [componentComplete](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#componentComplete) method and inside, called it's base class equavilent. `isComponentComplete()` returns true, but I'm still getting 0 from `width()` and `height()` methods:

```
void MyQQuickItem::componentComplete()
{
    QQuickItem::componentComplete();
    if(isComponentComplete())
    {
        qDebug() << "c++: oncompleted, width,height: " << width() << height(); //gives 0,0
    }

}
```

Actually I figured out that `Component.onCompleted` in QML prints 0's too:

```
...
MyQQuickItem
{
    width: parent.width / 2
    height: parent.height
    source: "someSource"
    Component.onCompleted
    {
        console.log("component onCompleted width, height: ", width, height); //it gives 0 too
    }
}
```

@derM `Component.onCompleted` is not emmited by `QQuickItem::componentComplete()` directly, because it prints its log after the qDebug in c++ above.

So, although it is ready, properties are not initialized.

**EDIT2:**

Finally I've solved it. The [Window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) was guilty, because it uses `contentItem` as the parent of his childrens, and in MyQQuickItem `Component.onCompleted` `width` and `height` of `contentItem`(his parent) are 0.

When I do so:

```
Window
{
    id: wnd
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        console.log("Window completed: ", this, width, height);
        console.log("windowContentItem: ", contentItem, width, height);
    }

    MyQQuickItem
    {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            console.log("MyQQuickItem completed: ", this, width, height);
            console.log("MyQQuickItem parent: ", parent, parent.width, parent.height);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
qml: Window completed:  QQuickWindowQmlImpl(0x345b5eb4d0) 640 480
qml: windowContentItem:  QQuickRootItem(0x345e2cdec0) 640 480
qml: MyQQuickItem completed:  MyQQuickItem(0x345b5b99e0) 0 0
qml: MyQQuickItem parent:  QQuickRootItem(0x345e2cdec0) 0 0
```

So `MyQQuickItem` `parent` is `Window`'s `contentItem`. When I replace

```
width: parent.width
height: parent.height
```

to:

```
width: wnd.width
height: wnd.height
```

It works perfectly, and in my `void MyQQuickItem::componentComplete()` I've got `width` and `height` initialized as expected.

One thing that I do not understand is why in `Window` `onCompleted`, `contentItem` size is correct, but in `MyQQuickItem` `onCompleted` the size is 0,0. If anyone could explain it to me, I would be grateful :P

Comment: The [MCVE](/help/mcve) is still missing. It would include a complete QML file, so that the whole setup actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: @derM Check EDIT2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qt code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/quicktemplates2/qquickcontrol.cpp#n1288) uses [`componentComplete()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#componentComplete) like so:

```
void QQuickControl::componentComplete()
{
    Q_D(QQuickControl);
    QQuickItem::componentComplete();
    d->resizeContent();
    // ...
}
```

You can do something similar, replacing `resizeContent()` with your function that works on the `width` and `height`. Assuming that function is also called whenever `source` changes, you'd need the `isComponentComplete()` check. With this approach, you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Sorry, but I said it too early. `isComponentComplete()` actually returns true, after calling `QQuickItem::componentComplete()`  but `width` and `height` are still 0

Comment: Maybe `Component.onCompleted` might be emitted in `QQuickItem::componentComplete()`? So if you follow the documentation and call the base class method first, the signal will be emitted before you have the dimensions. Try to move `QQuickItem::componentComplete()` to the end of the function despite what the documentation tells you, and see if nothing crashes :S

Comment: @Macias: a minimal complete example would help in answering your question.

Comment: @Mitch I've edited my question and actually you gives the correct answer, but It was not exacly what I meant :f

Answer (score -1):

You can inherit [QQmlParserStatus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlparserstatus.html) and implement componentComplete().

```
class MyQQuickItem : public QQuickItem, public QQmlParserStatus
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QUrl source MEMBER m_source NOTIFY sourceChanged)

public:
    explicit MyQQuickItem(QQuickItem *a_parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~PDFPage();

    void classBegin();
    void componentComplete();

signals:
    void sourceChanged(const QUrl a_source);

private:
    QUrl m_source;
};
```

componentComplete() will be called automatically by the QML-engine.

Comment: You will not be able to inherit from both QQuickItem and QQmlParserStatus because QQuickItem itself inherits from QQmlParserStatus

Comment: Yeah, right! But then skip inheter QQmlParserStatus and just override classBegin() and componentComplete().